# Facing issue in passing a list or array of values through json

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

**Scenario**

I am passing a array list through json to a api method. The call is successful and when we see the list it shows the count of the number of objects passed but the values within the objects are not set please help.

My object:

```
var datavalue = [{
        BeerId: 1,
        BeerName: "KingFisher",
        XCoordinates: 45,
        YCoordinates: 56
    },
    {
        BeerId: 2,
        BeerName: "KingFisher(Strong)",
        XCoordinates: 47,
        YCoordinates: 58
    }];
```

My json call:

```
 $.ajax({ //actually approve or reject the promotion
        url: 'api/BeerAppGroup/GetRegistered',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(datavalue),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
}});
```

My api method:

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "GET, POST")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult GetRegistered(List<UserBeerDetailContact> datavalue)
        {
            BeerAppUserClass beerAppDal = new BeerAppUserClass();
            return Json(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("IsRegistered", ""));

        }
```

Definition of class:

```
[Serializable]
    public class UserBeerDetailContact
    {
        public Int32 BeerId { get; set; }
        public String BeerName { get; set; }
        public Int32 XCoordinates { get; set; }
        public Int32 YCoordinates { get; set; }

    }
```

We are getting count 2 in the list. But the values in each object is null.

Please help how to get the values also within it.

Comment: The api method `GetRegistered` does absolutely nothing with the parameter `dataValue`. You are creating an instance of BeerAppUserClass, but you never do anything with it. You are returning a `new KeyValuePair<String, String>("IsRegistered", "")`, the empty quotes mean you are not setting the `value` of the `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: Please include the definition of `UserBeerDetailContact`.

Comment: And `BeerAppUserClass` while you're at it.

Comment: I will use the object, I havent shared the logical part. Its just I don't get the values in the list though it shows the correct count..

Answer (score 0):

```
            var invoiceObj = {};
            invoiceObj["InvoiceId"] = 0;
            invoiceObj["BuyerName"] = $("#txtByerName").val();
            invoiceObj["BuyerEmail"] = $("#txtByerEmail").val();
            invoiceObj["InvoiceNumber"] = $("#txtInvoiceNo").val();
            invoiceObj["InvoiceDate"] = $("#txtInvoiceDate").val();
            invoiceObj["InvoiceDueDate"] = $("#txtInvoiceDueDate").val();
            invoiceObj["InvoiceCurrency"] = $("#ddlCurency").val()
            invoiceObj["Reference"] = $("#txtRef").val();
            invoiceObj["InvoiceTotal"] = Total;

JSON.stringify(invoiceObj),
```

try to make your javascript object like above code and than stringify it by using JSON object